# No internet connection after sleep although Wi-Fi connected and working well, Android Samsung Galaxy S I9000

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s, connection-issues, 4.1-jelly-bean, standby

Problem: No internet connection after 1+ minutes of sleep. Wi-Fi is still connected, i have IP assigned through DHCP, i can browse shared folders on PC in network. It looks similar as if i didn't allow WAN traffic for my MAC on my router (Old PC with floppy Coyote Linux router)

Temporary solution: Turn Wi-Fi off and on again.

Phone: Samsung Galaxy I9000, custom JB rom (latest CM10), custom JB kernel (latest Semaphore)

This problem is bothering me for a month now. I did following things trying to solve the issue:

1. Switched kernels (Semaphore, CM9, CM10, Devil's Kernel) (over CWM)
2. Switched ROM's (CM9, HellyBean, CM10) (over CWM)
3. Replaced XXJVT with XXJVU baseband only (over Odin, but got stuck without IMEI, phone number and data connection)
4. Changed encryption of AP from WPA to WPA2
5. Changed Wi-Fi channels from 11 to 6
6. Changed Wi-Fi from G to B+G
7. Switched off AP's QoS
8. Turned off router's firewall
9. Tried few Wi-Fi keep-alive apks
10. Rebooted Access Point, Router
11. Set "Always" in "Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep"
12. Disabled "Avoid poor connections"
13. Searched Google and forums, posted questions
14. Turned off Powersave Wi-Fi mode on kernel manager
15. Checked logcat (on the bottom see logcat within few minutes when connection was lost after screen turned off)
16. Used "forget network" for home Wi-Fi

I haven't flashed stock firmware all over again yet. I don't want to go through the process of reinstalling all the apps and accounts (Play doesn't want to restore them for some reason)

---

```
$08-26 09:47:00.800 D/SurfaceFlinger(  489): About to give-up screen, flinger = 0x419caaf0
$08-26 09:47:06.011 I/goggles ( 1726): BaseApplication: Getting userWantsHistory = false
$08-26 09:47:06.421 D/dalvikvm( 1726): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1870K, 66% free 2808K/8195K, paused 72ms+3ms, total 231ms
$08-26 09:47:06.421 D/dalvikvm( 1726): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 112ms
$08-26 09:47:06.507 I/goggles ( 1726): FreshnessHelper: Checking for images newer than 1345938048000
$08-26 09:47:15.324 V/LockPatternKeyguardView(  664): Set visibility on com.android.internal.policy.impl.LockPatternKeyguardView$5@4191ecb8 to 8388608
$08-26 09:47:15.511 V/TransportControlView(  664): Create TCV com.android.internal.widget.TransportControlView@418c5560
$08-26 09:47:15.824 V/KeyguardViewManager(  664): KGVM: Set visibility on com.android.internal.policy.impl.KeyguardViewManager$KeyguardViewHost@40edc000 to 6291456
$08-26 09:47:15.839 D/PhoneStatusBar(  945): disable: < expand icons alerts ticker system_info back home RECENT* clock >
$08-26 09:47:16.019 D/dalvikvm(  664): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2953K, 41% free 13847K/23175K, paused 13ms+46ms, total 218ms
$08-26 09:47:16.019 D/dalvikvm(  664): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 120ms
$08-26 09:47:16.050 V/LockPatternKeyguardView(  664): Set visibility on com.android.internal.policy.impl.LockPatternKeyguardView$5@4191ecb8 to 8388608
$08-26 09:47:16.054 D/PhoneStatusBar(  945): disable: < expand icons alerts ticker system_info BACK* HOME* RECENT CLOCK* >
$08-26 09:47:16.144 V/LockPatternKeyguardView(  664): Set visibility on com.android.internal.policy.impl.LockPatternKeyguardView$5@4191ecb8 to 8388608
$08-26 09:48:07.023 I/goggles ( 1726): BaseApplication: Getting userWantsHistory = false
$08-26 09:48:07.281 I/goggles ( 1726): FreshnessHelper: Checking for images newer than 1345938048000
$08-26 09:48:19.023 D/ConnectivityService(  664): ConnectivityChange for WIFI: CONNECTED/CONNECTED
$08-26 09:48:19.027 D/ConnectivityService(  664): handleConnectivityChange: address are the same reset per doReset linkProperty[1]: resetMask=0
$08-26 09:48:19.050 D/ConnectivityService(  664): ConnectivityChange for WIFI: CONNECTED/CONNECTED
$08-26 09:48:19.058 D/ConnectivityService(  664): handleConnectivityChange: address are the same reset per doReset linkProperty[1]: resetMask=0
$[COLOR="red"]08-26 09:48:20.027 D/ConnectivityService(  664): NetTransition Wakelock for WifiStateMachine released by timeout[/COLOR]
$08-26 09:49:02.027 D/Sensors (  664): Smb380Sensor::~enable(0, 1)
$08-26 09:49:02.027 D/Sensors (  664): Smb380Sensor::~enable(0, 1) open /sys/class/input/event1/device/enable
$08-26 09:49:02.027 D/Sensors (  664): Smb380Sensor::~enable(0, 1) opened /sys/class/input/event1/device/enable
$08-26 09:49:02.035 D/Sensors (  664): Smb380Sensor::~setDelay(0, 200000000)
$08-26 09:49:02.035 D/Sensors (  664): Smb380Sensor::~setDelay(0, 66667000)
$08-26 09:49:02.187 I/WindowManager(  664): Lock screen displayed!
$08-26 09:49:02.210 D/SurfaceFlinger(  489): Screen about to return, flinger = 0x419caaf0
$08-26 09:49:02.472 D/Tethering(  664): MasterInitialState.processMessage what=3
$08-26 09:49:02.609 D/Tethering(  664): MasterInitialState.processMessage what=3
$08-26 09:49:03.003 [COLOR="Red"]D/ConnectivityService(  664): handleInetConditionHoldEnd: net=1, condition=100, published condition=0[/COLOR]
$08-26 09:49:03.214 D/PicasaUploaderSyncManager(24298): active network: NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
$08-26 09:49:03.214 D/PicasaUploaderSyncManager(24298): background data: true
$08-26 09:49:03.496 W/ContextScopeImpl(24312): thread=1 tried to enter the scope of the application context. Ignored.
$08-26 09:49:03.503 W/ContextScopeImpl(24312): thread=1 tried to enter the scope of the application context. Ignored.
$08-26 09:49:03.519 I/goggles ( 1726): BaseApplication: Getting userWantsHistory = false
$08-26 09:49:03.691 I/goggles ( 1726): FreshnessHelper: Checking for images newer than 1345938048000
$08-26 09:49:03.917 D/PicasaSyncManager(22933): active network: NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
$08-26 09:49:03.917 D/PicasaSyncManager(22933): background data: true
$08-26 09:49:04.074 W/ContextScopeImpl(24312): thread=1 tried to enter the scope of the application context. Ignored.
$08-26 09:49:04.082 W/ContextScopeImpl(24312): thread=1 tried to enter the scope of the application context. Ignored.
$08-26 09:49:04.093 I/goggles ( 1726): BaseApplication: Getting userWantsHistory = false
$08-26 09:49:04.187 D/PicasaUploaderSyncManager(24298): active network: NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
$08-26 09:49:04.222 D/PicasaUploaderSyncManager(24298): background data: true
$08-26 09:49:04.246 D/PicasaSyncManager(22933): active network: NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
$08-26 09:49:04.246 D/PicasaSyncManager(22933): background data: true
$08-26 09:49:04.464 D/dalvikvm( 1726): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1854K, 66% free 2797K/8195K, paused 81ms+67ms, total 245ms
$08-26 09:49:04.464 D/dalvikvm( 1726): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 136ms
$08-26 09:49:04.503 I/goggles ( 1726): FreshnessHelper: Checking for images newer than 1345938048000
$08-26 09:49:06.394 I/ActivityManager(  664): Process com.tmobile.thememanager (pid 24054) has died.
$08-26 09:49:12.039 D/Sensors (  664): Smb380Sensor::~enable(0, 0)
$08-26 09:49:12.050 D/Sensors (  664): Smb380Sensor::~enable(0, 0) open /sys/class/input/event1/device/enable
$08-26 09:49:12.050 D/Sensors (  664): Smb380Sensor::~enable(0, 0) opened /sys/class/input/event1/device/enable
$08-26 09:49:12.066 D/Sensors (  664): Smb380Sensor::~setDelay(0, 66667000)
$08-26 09:49:12.441 D/dalvikvm(  664): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2495K, 39% free 14281K/23175K, paused 18ms+11ms, total 137ms
$08-26 09:49:12.441 D/dalvikvm(  664): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 109ms
$08-26 09:49:12.445 D/dalvikvm(  664): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 79ms
$08-26 09:49:12.457 V/TransportControlView(  664): Create TCV com.android.internal.widget.TransportControlView@40e3b4f8
$08-26 09:49:12.570 D/SurfaceFlinger(  489): About to give-up screen, flinger = 0x419caaf0
$08-26 09:49:12.656 V/LockPatternKeyguardView(  664): Set visibility on com.android.internal.policy.impl.LockPatternKeyguardView$5@4191ecb8 to 8388608
$08-26 09:49:12.687 V/LockPatternKeyguardView(  664): Set visibility on com.android.internal.policy.impl.LockPatternKeyguardView$5@4191ecb8 to 8388608
$[COLOR="Red"]08-26 09:49:23.093 W/ThrottleService(  664): unable to find stats for iface pdp0[/COLOR]
$08-26 09:50:07.011 I/goggles ( 1726): BaseApplication: Getting userWantsHistory = false
$08-26 09:50:07.203 I/goggles ( 1726): FreshnessHelper: Checking for images newer than 1345938048000
$08-26 09:50:08.261 D/dalvikvm(  664): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
$08-26 09:50:08.382 D/dalvikvm(  664): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1119K, 38% free 14381K/23175K, paused 8ms+8ms, total 121ms
$08-26 09:50:44.695 D/ConnectivityService(  664): ConnectivityChange for WIFI: CONNECTED/CONNECTED
$08-26 09:50:44.707 D/ConnectivityService(  664): handleConnectivityChange: address are the same reset per doReset linkProperty[1]: resetMask=0
$08-26 09:50:44.718 D/ConnectivityService(  664): ConnectivityChange for WIFI: CONNECTED/CONNECTED
$08-26 09:50:44.734 D/ConnectivityService(  664): handleConnectivityChange: address are the same reset per doReset linkProperty[1]: resetMask=0
$[COLOR="red"]08-26 09:50:45.699 D/ConnectivityService(  664): NetTransition Wakelock for WifiStateMachine released by timeout[/COLOR]
$08-26 09:51:07.242 I/goggles ( 1726): BaseApplication: Getting userWantsHistory = false
$08-26 09:51:07.421 I/goggles ( 1726): FreshnessHelper: Checking for images newer than 1345938048000
$08-26 09:51:07.425 D/Tethering(  664): MasterInitialState.processMessage what=3
$08-26 09:51:07.453 D/Tethering(  664): MasterInitialState.processMessage what=3
$08-26 09:51:07.589 W/ContextScopeImpl(24312): thread=1 tried to enter the scope of the application context. Ignored.
$08-26 09:51:07.609 W/ContextScopeImpl(24312): thread=1 tried to enter the scope of the application context. Ignored.
$08-26 09:51:07.625 I/goggles ( 1726): BaseApplication: Getting userWantsHistory = false
$08-26 09:51:07.625 D/PicasaUploaderSyncManager(24298): active network: NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
$08-26 09:51:07.828 D/PicasaSyncManager(22933): active network: NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
$08-26 09:51:07.863 D/dalvikvm( 1726): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1840K, 66% free 2800K/8195K, paused 19ms+26ms, total 93ms
$08-26 09:51:07.863 D/dalvikvm( 1726): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 21ms
$08-26 09:51:07.910 I/goggles ( 1726): FreshnessHelper: Checking for images newer than 1345938048000
$08-26 09:51:07.933 D/PicasaUploaderSyncManager(24298): background data: true
$08-26 09:51:07.937 D/PicasaSyncManager(22933): background data: true
$08-26 09:51:07.964 D/PicasaUploaderSyncManager(24298): active network: NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
$08-26 09:51:07.964 D/PicasaUploaderSyncManager(24298): background data: true
```

Comment: What irritates me are the Tethering entries in your log. Not sure what they mean -- but are you sure your internet is going via Wifi? Maybe you could check from a terminal app using the `route` command whether routing maybe got messed up? Not that I knew the next step then...

Comment: First of all, i think the problem is gone after flashing XXJVU baseband=modem=radio via CWM the second time. I got modems here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1158783

Comment: If it stays solved, consider saying so (including the steps that solved it) by answering your own question, and then accepting your own answer. This way other people with similar problems can see right from the lists this question has a solution.

Comment: I have the answer ready, but have to wait for some time until the system allows me to post it. I will also include the results of your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

**I have solved the problem by flashing modem (aka baseband aka radio) only through CWM / recovery mode.**

This way i have kept all my settings and apk's and rom and kernel.

The files i have used (for SGS i9000) can be found here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1158783
You have to choose appropriate modem according to your phone/location/operator.

Perhaps it needs to be done twice or with correct modem (i suggest trying few times).

*My actual procedure (i don't suggest repeating it) was: flashing several tar.md5 modem files several times via Odin which didn't work and I've lost my IMEI and phone number and signal. Later i have restored backed up /efs folder bud didn't help with IMEI. Then i flashed zip modem files over CWM in recovery mode which solved both problems.*

Personally i have tried i9000xxjvu and i9000xwjw1 and both worked. After updating ROM with latest nightlies and later changing the kernel i notice that baseband version doesn't change.

This is probably why i couldn't solve the problem by changing roms and kernels before.

I read somewhere that modem does not affect Wi-Fi, but obviously it does to some degree.

Answer (score 0):

Flashing baseband via Odin lost my IMEI and phone number and connectivity. I have fixed this by flashing modem via CWM.

After that the disconnections have seemed to stop. Also another problem got solved - before i couldn't copy +200MB file from PC to Android via Samba Fileserver - something disconnected the process every time. Now i can copy 300MB file without disconnections.

I will wait for a day or two and try to mess with Wi-Fi settings and let you know if the problem is really solved.

Izzy: I am sure my internet was going through Wi-Fi. Now the logs are different than before flashing modem (or replacing kernel, although kernel didn't solve the problem). Here is what i get if i check what you suggested:

```
cat /proc/net/route
Iface   Destination     Gateway         Flags   RefCnt  Use     Metric  Mask            MTU     Window  IRTT
wlan0   00000000        0102A8C0        0003    0       0       0       00000000        0       0   0
wlan0   0002A8C0        00000000        0001    0       0       0       00FFFFFF        0       0   0
wlan0   0102A8C0        00000000        0005    0       0       0       FFFFFFFF        0       0   0
root@android:/ # netstat -nr
netstat -nr
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address          Foreign Address        State
 tcp       0      0 127.0.0.1:7777         0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
 tcp       0      0 127.0.0.1:7203         0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
 tcp       0      0 127.0.0.1:5037         0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
 tcp       0      0 0.0.0.0:5555           0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
 tcp      62      0 192.168.2.116:5555     192.168.2.100:12979    ESTABLISHED
 tcp       0      0 127.0.0.1:37807        127.0.0.1:7777         ESTABLISHED
 tcp       0      0 127.0.0.1:7777         127.0.0.1:37807        ESTABLISHED
 tcp       0      0 127.0.0.1:37806        127.0.0.1:7777         ESTABLISHED
 tcp       0      0 127.0.0.1:7777         127.0.0.1:37806        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:192.168.2.116:58387 ::ffff:173.194.70.188:5228 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      1 ::ffff:192.168.2.116:50048 ::ffff:173.194.35.147:443 CLOSE_WAIT
root@android:/ #
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problem after flashing a new ROM.

For me exempting `com.qualcomm.qti.tetherservice` service from Battery Saver worked. You have to choose "Don't Optimize" in order for it to work correctly.