# Which modem firmware for Samsung Galaxy S (GT-I9000) works best with the mobile networks in Russia?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, mobile-network, radio-firmware, localization

Trying to use a Samsung Galaxy S device coming from China or Korea in Russia [lead to the observation that the quality of the connection to the mobile network is much worse](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/44021/13117) than on Samsung Galaxy S we used previously (which was bought in Russia).

I have installed CyanogenMod 10.0 on the device in the hope that the mobile network connection quality would improve. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

Now I see information that there are different firmware available for the modem; one should try to flash them to get modem working well in a specific region --https://android.stackexchange.com/a/44021/13117:

> Well, I guess you should flash another modem file, which is working
>   well for your region/carrier (use google . A modem file defines how
>   the radio part of your phone works, it has an influence on signal
>   strenght/network speed (and might have influence on battery life,
>   too).

and http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1158783 lists a lot various modem firmware for the device.

Which one to choose for Russia, Moscow (Megafon mobile network)?

(The one that was working bad for us is XXJPK, and--on another device from China or Korea--SPJG2, which also has bad/unstable signal, but not as bad as XXJPK. After the installation of CM10, XXJPK on that device was replaced with XXJVT, which again has very bad signal.)

Comment: Don't confuse device-firmware with radio-firmware. When talking about "modem file", this most likely rather refers to the latter. Watch out for a fitting RUU (RadioUnitUpdate), not ROM (e.g. CyanogenMod). For details, you might want to check the corresponding tag wikis, e.g. [radio-firmware tag wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/radio-firmware/info).

Comment: Perhaps I should take into account this experience: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/28397/13117 .

Comment: I want to try JW1, JW4, JVU firmware -- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=30857771&postcount=1277 : "JVU: Great battery life, ok signal, ok call quality
JW4: Awesome battery life, good signal, ok call quality
JW1: Ok battery life, Awesome signal, awesome call quality
" But another post says JVT was better than JVU in Germany -- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=26491440&postcount=1084 , so I'm in doubt (because XXJVT from CM10 works badly for us).

Answer (score 1):

(Initially, the device had XXJPK radio firmware, and it worked bad in Moscow (Megafon operator). Another device had SPJG2 radio firmware, and it worked a bit better here.)

Then I tried:

- XXJVT, which was installed together with CM10. And it worked almost as bad again (no signal in our apartment, where previously another Samsung Galaxy S had connection);
- JW1, JW4 (`radio-cm-7-GalaxyS-JW4-signed.zip`), which were bad again;
- `Modem_XXJVT-CWM3.zip` (again XXJVT) couldn't be installed into my device with CM10 from my CWM-based recovery (something incompatible); `radio-cm-7-GalaxyS-JVT-signed.zip`, which worked bad;
- and, finally, **[`ZSJPG_ICS.CM.I9000.zip`](http://cyanogenmod.nl/files/Samsung%20Galaxy%20S/CM10/Modem%20%20Radio/ZSJPG_ICS.CM.I9000.zip) (from [CM10 files](http://cyanogenmod.nl/files/?dir=Samsung%20Galaxy%20S/CM10/Modem%20%20Radio)) works better!** -- it has better signal in many places (but not as good as some other old mobile telephones with the same SIM card in the same places). (I saw a good reference to ZSJPG in [a message at xda-developers from April 2012](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=25011144&postcount=21): "What do you prefer for a good stable rom in Holland? -- ZSJPG..best modem ever made"; I started searching for it because I saw it among the popular/most-downloaded radio-modem-firmwares for SGS [at 4pda.ru (in Russian)](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=222559&st=3220#entry8170381); in [another thread at 4pda.ru (in Russian)](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=195273&st=4600#entry7024329), it is listed among the modems for Asia, and there is a comment below saying that JPG was the only one that worked good for that person in an office building.)

(Feel free to give other good tested radio firmwares here, if you have some experience or information!)

Comment: But even the best results on this device (this instance) are very bad; much worse than on another such device or other phones. So I believe it has broken hardware.